# Get data from array columns in databricks without cross joining

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a table :

| id | array_col |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | [{"system": "x", "value": "1"}, {"system": "y", "value": "2"},{"system": "z", "value": "3"}] |

Where array_col basically contains an array of structures

0: {"system": "x", "value": "1"}

1: {"system": "y", "value": "2"}

2: {"system": "z", "value": "3"}

I need the output like the following table:

| id | system | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | x | 1 |
| 101 | y | 2 |
| 101 | z | 3 |

Right now I'm trying to use explode in sub queries (Since can't have multiple explode in a single select statement, and then joining them based on id. But that is giving me an output where each system is showing for each value, so instead of 3 i'm getting 9 results.

| id | system | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | x | 1 |
| 101 | x | 2 |
| 101 | x | 3 |
| 101 | y | 1 |
| 101 | y | 2 |
| 101 | y | 3 |
| 101 | z | 1 |
| 101 | z | 2 |
| 101 | z | 3 |

Help me get the output with 3 rows, instead of 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `inline`:

```
df.selectExpr('id', 'inline(array_col)').show()
+---+------+-----+
| id|system|value|
+---+------+-----+
|101|     x|    1|
|101|     y|    2|
|101|     z|    3|
+---+------+-----+
```

The above assumes that the arrays contains structs, not structs as strings. If your structs are strings, you need to parse them with `from_json` first:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'id', 'explode(array_col) array_col'
).selectExpr(
    'id', "inline(array(from_json(array_col, 'struct<system:string, value:string>')))"
)

df2.show()
+---+------+-----+
| id|system|value|
+---+------+-----+
|101|     x|    1|
|101|     y|    2|
|101|     z|    3|
+---+------+-----+
```